# Vanishing second cohomology with coefficients in a $p$-adic vector space

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, p-adic-number-theory, group-cohomology

Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete group, and $V$ a (not necessarily finite-dimensional) $\mathbb{Q}_p[\Gamma]$-module. I am looking for general criteria that ensure that $H^2(\Gamma, V) = 0$.

The simplest example is with $\Gamma$ free or finite. Using the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence, one can also show that this is true when $\Gamma$ is virtually free. Are there any other interesting examples?

I am particularly interested in finitely presented examples.

Comment: If $\Gamma$ is torsion free (no other conditions assumed) then your condition is already enough to show that $\Gamma$ is actually free (https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81992726.pdf).

Comment: @user760870 the result you linked requires vanishing in all degrees at least 2. Does vanishing in degree 2 automatically imply vanishing in higher degrees?

Comment: Yes; $K[G]$ has enough injectives, so consider $0 \rightarrow V \rightarrow I \rightarrow I/V \rightarrow 0$; then $H^n(\Gamma,V) = H^{n-1}(\Gamma,I/V)$.